# supabase query for one-to-one foreign key, return single value (not array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, supabase-database

How can I query a one-to-one relationship with foreign key in supabase?

My tables:

1. games (id, created_at, played_at)
2. results (game_id, key)

Data: games

```
("id": 1, "created_at": "2022-03-02T11:01:11+00:00", "played_at": "2022-04-02T12:15:06+00:00")
```

Data: results

```
("game_id": 1, "key": "alyktm3cf11bypgg")
```

My supabase query looks like this:

```
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('games')
        .select('*, registrations(walletKey), results(key)')
        .order('scheduled_at')
    ;
```

The result contains an array of registrations, like here:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-03-02T11:01:11+00:00",
    "played_at": "2022-04-02T12:15:06+00:00",
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "alyktm3cf11bypgg"
        }
    ]
}
```

But since there will always only be one result, can I modify my query to get this?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-03-02T11:01:11+00:00",
    "played_at": "2022-04-02T12:15:06+00:00",
    "results": 
    {
        "key": "alyktm3cf11bypgg"
    }

}
```

Or even this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-03-02T11:01:11+00:00",
    "played_at": "2022-04-02T12:15:06+00:00",
    "key": "alyktm3cf11bypgg"
}
```

Comment: If it's okay to convert post-facto (using vanilla JS), then may be give this a try: `const newDataObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(oldDataObj).map(([k, v]) => (k !== 'results' ? [k, v] : ["key", v?.[0]?.key])));`. I assume the objective is not this - but rather get the result from directly in the format.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the [`single()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/single) method:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('games')
    .select('*, registrations(walletKey), results(key)')
    .order('scheduled_at')
    .single();
```

Note, that if the query does NOT return a single row, the method will return an error (i.e. the `data` field will be `undefined` or `null` while the `error` field will be defined).